# Text box for searching MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm learning WPF C # with a simple application that I'm trying to do. I'm wondering how do I create a text box to search. For example: The user enters any name and as he enters the application shows the similar names below the gift box of the text box.

Researched on some sites, but found people writing much code in the Code-Behind and this solution does not interest me.

Comment: do a google search on `C# WPF textbox search` what have you tried on your own..?

Comment: I searched but did not find what he wanted. @MethodMan Would you have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are interested in MVVM, this is my idea:

- bind a string in to the view model to the `Text` property of the `TextBox`
- implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the view model
- implement view model's `PropertyChanged` event in the model (presenter) and trigger some action on every change (meaning on every change of the contents of the `TextBox`)

Make sure that the binding on the `TextBox` is set to `Mode=TwoWay` (although I belive that is already by default)

Comment: Thank you for your tip. As I said , I'm learning now. I wanted to ask you what the best method ? Which method that professional developers use ?

Comment: Well this is how it would be implemented using MVVM. MVVM is a pattern, there is no best or worst way - you either follow it or not.